# Does Rails overwrite ruby's default logger?

Tags: ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.6

I'm writing a multilogger implementation in order to enable my application to log to multiple back ends. The implementation looks like:

```rb
class MultiLogger < Logger
  def initialize(loggers = [])
    @loggers = []
  end

  def add(severity, message, _attributes, _environment, progname)
    @loggers.each do |logger|
      logger.add(severity, message, progname)
    end
  end

  def info(message, attributes, environment, progname)
    add(Logger::INFO, message, attributes, environment, progname)
  end

  ...
end
```

Basically I'm only forwarding calls issued to `MultiLogger#add` to all the loggers associated during the instantiation. The problem is that I need to set that logger as the Rails' default one, but I can't do that.

I'm adding `config.logger = MultiLogger.new([Logger1.new, Logger2.new])` to my `application.rb` file, but when I call `logger.info`, I'm getting an error related to the arity of the `add` method.

The strangest thing is that my custom add is never called, and that error is raised from `ActiveSupport::LogerThreadSafeLevel#add`, like this: `.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:51:in 'add'`.

I think I'm missing something important about the inner workings of the Rails logging mechanism... but what? Is `ActiveSupport` overwriting my `add` method? What can I do in order to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

### Use ActiveSupport::Logger or Modify Application Configuration File

By default, Rails expects the logger to be an instance of ActiveSupport::Logger. However, you can modify application.rb to use something else that's compatible. The [Rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#what-is-the-logger-questionmark) says:

> **2.1 What is the Logger?**
>
> Rails makes use of the ActiveSupport::Logger class to write log
> information. Other loggers, such as Log4r, may also be substituted.
>
> You can specify an alternative logger in config/application.rb or any
> other environment file[.]

Answer (score 0):

Rails expects the Logger#add method to follow the interface of the Ruby logger, that is one mandatory argument (the `severity`), followed by two optional arguments (the `message` and the `progname`) as well as an optional block.

Here, Rails also assumed very specific semantics how these arguments are used by a logger implementation to build the final message (when passing either a `message`, a `progname`, a block or any combination of it.

```
class MultiLogger
  def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
    @loggers.each do |logger|
      logger.add(severity, message, progname, &block)
    end
    true
  end

  def info(message = nil, &block)
    add(Logger::INFO, message, &block)
  end

  # ...
end
```

In your original code, you have defined additional mandatory parameters in your `add` method (namely `_attributes` and `_environment`) which are not provided when calling the method thus an Exception. Once you fix your parameter list (and implement the missing shortcut methods and accessors), everything should work.